# Add '0b' to byte

Tags: python, binary

I have a program in which I need to convert for example a variable containing the string `'01000100'` to `0b01000100` so I can decode it to the corresponding symbol, in this case, the letter `'D'` using the built in `chr()` function. How is it possible to do this conversion or is there an easier way to convert the string to the corresponding symbol?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to add the `0b`, you just need to call the `int` constructor appropriately, passing a second argument of `2` so it knows the input is in base 2.

```
chr(int('01000100', 2))
```